# How do I delete select telemetry data, streams from a Heila?

Tags: data-stream

It is ideal to keep all the data until you can't. When there is a need to delete data, it doesn't necessarily have to be from all the streams. There might be data in some streams that we might want to keep. The current approach does not let the user select streams to delete the telemetry data from but rather purges data from all the streams.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to add four new functions to the existing purge script which now enables the user to select streams to purge data from.

Steps -

1. First run the purge script
   `python purge.py`
   This will show you three menu options. The last option is `3 -- Purge selected streams`.
2. Upon selecting the third option, a list of streams is displayed. The script prompts you to select stream(s) to purge. Enter a comma-separated list of stream names. If the stream name(s) is/are incorrect, you will be prompted to try one more time.
3. Enter the number of days older than today to purge data. Confirm with a y/n. If the input is y, data will be purged from all the streams with id corresponding to the stream names you input. Lastly, a list of all the streams the data was purged from is printed. If the input is n, you will be taken back to the main menu.

To explain the code a little;

- The first function is `get_streams` which fetches all the stream names and corresponding IDs from the stream table and stores them as key-value pairs in a dictionary.
- The second function is `list_streams` which calls the `get_streams` function to get the dictionary and the existing `get_stream_tables` function to get all the streams corresponding to each ID in the stream table. It prints a list of streams (say, socomec 0, generator 11 etc.) for users to choose from.
- The third function is `stream_input` which takes a comma-separated input from the user and checks if the stream name(s) input by the user exists or not. If the input is incorrect, it prompts the user to try again (one time only). If the input is correct, it takes the ID(s) and appends 'stream' in front of it and filters out all the streams corresponding to that particular ID, using a lambda function, into a list. It then prompts the user to enter the number of days and provide confirmation.
- The fourth function , `purge_stream`, is a slight modification of the original `purge` function. The loop variable in this function is the list of streams that we get from the lambda function mentioned above which ensures that the data is purged only from the selected streams.